# Find The Volume of the solid in the first octant , limit by: $ x^2+y^2=4 $ and $z+y=3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid in the first octant , limit by:  $ x^2+y^2=4  $ and $z+y=3$.

$x$  and $y$ range from $0$ to $2$.

$$\int_0^2 \int_0^2  y-3 \,dy\,dx $$

is correct?

[image: The draw]

Comment: Obviously not, since $x^2+y^2=4$ doesn't come into play in your integral.

Comment: How , i can add in the integral?

Comment: You should draw the region of integration, which is the portion inside the circle within the first quadrant. You will see that within that region the value of $x$ ranges over the interval $[0,2]$ which forms the limits of the outer integral $\int\cdots dx$.  Draw a vertical line within the region crossing at some $x$ between $0$ and $1$. The value of $y$ on the $x$-axis (i.e. $y=0$) is the lower limit of the inner integral $dy$ and the upper limit the value of $y$ as a function of $x$ where the vertical line intersects the circle is the upper limit of the interior integral.

Comment: You say find the interesactions in $ x2+y2=4x2+y2=4  and z+y=3z+y=3 $. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if $0\le y\le2$ then we are going to need to integrate (3-y) or we will get a negative number.

To find the limits of y, I suggest you draw a line that is parallel to the y-axis.
How would you represent the endpoints of this segment?

$x^2 + y^2 = 4\\
y^2 = 4-x^2\\
y = \sqrt{4-x^2}$

$\int_0^{2} \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}  (3-y) dydx$

Now, if you want to convert to cylindrical, that is up to you, and probably not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are working with a cynlinder, it is easier to work with cylindrical coordinate.

$y=r\sin \theta.$

Also, notice that the hyperplane intersect the cylinder above $z=0$.

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^2 (3-r\sin\theta) rdrd\theta$$

Comment: But if i want use rectangular Coordinates , how i can transform your integral?

Comment: As $x$ goes from $0$ to $2$, $y$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-x^2}$.

Comment: Oki  , thanks soo much for your help